# python 3: kivyException: Invalid instance in App.root

Tags: kivy, python-3.6

attempt to add widgets
trying to make a loginscreen

[written code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxYo6.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIgUF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your root widget object

```
...
return something() # notice the parentheses
```

also I think you need a `GridLayout` instead of `BoxLayout`